# Parsing ansible output in shell script using sed/grep

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, grep, ansible

I have a shell script which executes an ansible playbook and I want to process the output of this playbook. I am not sure how can I do this.

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/sh
ansible-playbook -i inventory/ec2.py services_status.yml
```

The output of ansible-playbook command is:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [cmx_running_services] ****************************************************
ok: [172.31.35.225]

ok: [172.31.9.253]


TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [172.31.35.225] => {
    "services": {
        "changed": false,
        "meta": {
            "services": [
                "zk",
                "kafka"
            ]
        }
    }
}

ok: [172.31.9.253] => {
    "services": {
        "changed": false,
        "meta": {
            "MyService": [
                "default"
            ],
            "services": [
                "monitoring-agent"
            ]
        }
    }
}


PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
172.31.35.225              : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
172.31.9.253               : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

In my script I want to process this output and store a json object in format:

```
{
  "172.31.35.225":{
    "services":[
      "zk",
      "kafka"
    ]
  },
  "172.31.9.253":{
    "MyService":[
      "default"
    ],
    "services":[
      "monitoring-agent"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can print the result of the playbook as a json then parse it in modern language like Python. All you need to do is set an environment variable ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json

Example:

```
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json ansible-playbook -i hosts.ini main.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is forget using `sed` or `awk` on Ansible log, which would become enormously complicated, and instead develop or customise a callback plugin.

Most likely you should start with the example [`json.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/json.py) which outputs the Ansible log in JSON format (at least theoretically, as the example code does not seem to work out-of-the-github).

More on developing and configuration of [callback plugins](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#callback-plugins) in the official Ansible docs.